# Using fill_between() with a Pandas Data Series

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have graphed (using matplotlib) a time series and its associated upper and lower confidence interval bounds (which I calculated in Stata).  I used Pandas to read the stata.csv output file and so the series are of type pandas.core.series.Series.

Matplotlib allows me to graph these three series on the same plot, but I wish to shade between the upper and lower confidence bounds to generate a visual confidence interval.  Unfortunately I get an error, and the shading doesn't work.  I think this is to do with the fact that the functions between which I wish to fill are pandas.core.series.Series.

Another post on here suggests that passing my_series.value instead of my_series will fix this problem; however I cannot get this to work.  I'd really appreciate an example.

Comment: Can you attach an example of what have you accomplished so far, and what do you exactly want to accomplish?

Comment: I've deleted the Stata tag. It's incidental to your question that you are plotting the results of calculations in Stata. The tag would just lead Stata people here when there is no Stata question to answer. Reverse that if you think it's definitely wrong.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you don't have `NaN` values in your data, you should be okay:

```
In [78]: x = Series(linspace(0, 2 * pi, 10000))

In [79]: y = sin(x)

In [80]: fill_between(x.values, y.min(), y.values, alpha=0.5)
```

Which yields:

[image]

Comment: I'd advise against using the variable name `x` in this context, as this can be very confusing, seeing as how the horizontal axis in standard cathesian orientation is referred to as the x-axis (abscisse, or _first_ axis), while you plot your `x`-values along the vertical axis (ordinate, or _second_ axis). It would be more intuitive to use the variable name `y` here, especially since matplotlib follows the convention of the standard carthesian oritentaion.

Comment: My notation sees fairly standard use in signal processing and in texts on time series. I might understand your complaint if there were a ton of variables floating around, but my example is so simple that it doesn't really matter. The [wikipedia article on time series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) also uses this notation.

Comment: Whoa, I wasn't _complaining_ or saying that it's wrong. I know that _x(t)_ is fairly common notation, but so is _y(t)_. I just pointed out that `x` as a variable name plotted against the y-axis can be confusing in general, especially as the OP seems to be new to Python and matplotlib (given his username).

Comment: Ah. Okay, no problem then. I'd be happy to change it. Didn't mean to come off like that!